# How can I add css class to the to the nested element using DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have four child divs inside the container div, every child div has a button, image, and text inside. Images have to be `blurry` and text has to be `hidden` by default.

And when the user clicks the button, the button should be `hidden`, image and text should become `clear` and `visible`.

I'm trying to add or remove CSS classes from elements using for loop, but that just doesn't work at all...

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
let images = document.querySelectorAll(".img");
let imgTexts = document.querySelectorAll(".img-text");

images.forEach((el) => el.classList.add("blur"));
imgTexts.forEach((el) => el.classList.add("hidden"));
for (let i = 0; i < btns; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    btns[i].classList.add("hidden");
  });
}
```

```css
.blur {
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <button class="btn">Open the Gift</button>
        <img
          src=""
          alt="#" class="img">
        <p class="img-text">CONGRATULATIONS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <button class="btn">Open the Gift</button>
        <img
          src=""
          alt="#" class="img">
        <p class="img-text">CONGRATULATIONS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <button class="btn">Open the Gift</button>
        <img
          src=""
          alt="#" class="img">
        <p class="img-text">CONGRATULATIONS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <button class="btn">Open the Gift</button>
        <img
          src=""
          alt="#" class="img">
        <p class="img-text">CONGRATULATIONS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `i < btns` - `btns` is a collection of DOM nodes... -> `i < btns.length`

Comment: Why the `for` loop at all? Why not just another `.forEach()`?

Comment: When you've clear common container for the content, you might take the advantage from [Descendant combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinato) and/or [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator), that would make the code much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = 0; i < btns; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    btns[i].classList.add("hidden");
  });
}
```

Here, in the conditions of the for loop, write "i < btns.length".

Answer (score 0):

There is not a boundation that you can create only one class. You can create multiple classes and just on and add and remove the class according to your need.
example code
**HTML**

```
<img class = "image imageHidden" src = alt = >
<button class = "button buttonHidden">Click me</button>
```

now I created two classes at the same time I can use them to my need in javascript
**CSS**

```
.image {
visiblity: visible}
.imageHidden {
visibility: hidden}
.button {
visibility: visible}
.buttonHidden {
visibility: hidden}
```

now I used them in CSS that I can use in javascript

document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click",function () {

```
document.querySelector("img").classList.add("image");
document.querySelector("button").classList.add("buttonHidden");});
```

this code will hide the button and show the image you can use this method according to your need.